# Rob spent 25% more time on his research project than he had planned. He spent an extra h hours on the project.Khan Academy

Tags: percentages

The explanation says that he planned to spend $($h$/$25%$)$(100%) hours on the research project. How did they come up with the expression and i don't understand why the h is divided by the 25%. I do understand how it's manipulated to get to 5h but i just don't get how they came up with it in the first place

Comment: The number of hours Rob *actually* spent is in fact $5h$, not as the suggestion would imply $4h$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $H$ be the hours Bob planned to spend. Then $$h=\frac14 H.$$
Now the total amount of time spent is $$T=H+h=4h +h=5h.$$
With percents written
$$T=\frac{h}{25\,\%}+h.$$